# Вывод файла на html страницу с раскрашиванием определенных символов

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Моя программа генерирует .txt файл, файл сейчас содержит набор символов(до 16 тысяч), я хочу организовать вывод этого файла на html страницу, но чтобы каждый символ имел собственный стиль( цвет, фон )(без учета регистра). Тоесть если у меня лежит в файле слово "Код", то на выводе я хотел бы видеть:

> к - красная буква, черный фон
>
> о - зеленая буква, черный фон
>
> д - синяя буква, белый фон

Какими web инструментами вы бы решили эту задачу? точно css и html, а чем подгружать и бить файл?

*В последствии этот файл, думаю, будет отдавать мне набор цифр, которые я хотел бы превращать в символы и красить( это уже со стороны странички ). Так же хотелось бы иметь возможность заменять сам символ на определенную картинку ( о-красный зеленый квадрат, к - красный квадрат).*

Answer (score 1):

### JS. Пример перебора букв и создания элемента, помещение его в очередь, и последующая отрисовка с помощью `requestAnimationFrame`

`stackI` - число
как только массив `stack` заполнится на количество элементов `stackI` -  вызывается `requestAnimationFrame` затем продолжается заполнение очереди.

```js
{
  let genEl = (_color, _border) => {
    let el = document.createElement('span')
    el.style.color = _color
    el.style.border = _border
    return el
  }
  let dictHTML = {
    zero: genEl('#ffc256', ''),
    'А': genEl('red', 'solid 1px black'),
    'Б': genEl('green', 'solid 1px black'),
    'В': genEl('blue', 'solid 1px white'),
  }
  let str = `АБВ
 Моя программа генерирует .txt файл, файл сейчас содержит набор символов(до 16 тысяч),
 я хочу организовать вывод этого файла на html страницу,
 но чтобы каждый символ имел собственный стиль( цвет, фон )(без учета регистра).
 Тоесть если у меня лежит в файле слово "Код", то на выводе я хотел бы видеть:
 Моя программа генерирует .txt файл, файл сейчас содержит набор символов(до 16 тысяч),
 я хочу организовать вывод этого файла на html страницу, АБВ
 `
  let stack = []
  let stackI = 300
  let render = () => {
    console.log(`stack.length: ${stack.length}`)
    stack.forEach(_el => {
      document.body.appendChild(_el)
    })
    stack = []
    c.next()
  }
  console.log(`str.length: ${str.length}`);

  function* C() {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      let letter = String(str[i])
      let el = null;
      if (!(el = dictHTML[letter.toUpperCase()])) {
        el = dictHTML['zero']
      }
      el = el.cloneNode()
      el.innerHTML = letter
      stack.push(el)
      if (i % stackI == 0) yield requestAnimationFrame(render)
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render)
  }
  let c = C()
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
}
```

Comment: хотя это здесь не имеет значения, что-то у меня сомнения в правильности использования мной `requestAnimationFrame`